Google Analytics 4 GA4 Send Analytics from C# Visual Studio App
I am trying to send simple google analytics 4 GA4 data from my C# Windows Visual Studio App. I am using the following code. Visual Studio Console is reporting that the data is sent correctly, but my Google Analytics shows no real-time data and the DebugView in Google Analytics shows no data.
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public MainWindow()
{
     // Send analytics data when the application starts
     SendAnalyticsDataAsync("mainWindowOpened").ConfigureAwait(false);
}

private async Task SendAnalyticsDataAsync(string eventName)
 {
     var httpClient = new HttpClient();
     var measurementId = "MYMEASUREMENTID"; // Replace with Measurement ID
     var jsonPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
     {
         client_id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
         events = new List<object>
 {
     new
     {
         name = eventName
     }
 }
     });
     var content = new StringContent(jsonPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

     // Log additional information about the request
     Console.WriteLine($"Sending analytics data at {DateTime.UtcNow}");
     Console.WriteLine($"Event name: {eventName}");
     Console.WriteLine($"Payload: {jsonPayload}");

     var response = await httpClient.PostAsync($"https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?measurement_id={measurementId}", content);

     // Log the status code regardless of success or failure
     Console.WriteLine($"Status code: {response.StatusCode}");

     if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
     {
         // Handle success
         Console.WriteLine("Analytics data sent successfully.");
     }
     else
     {
         // Handle error
         // Optionally, log the response body for more details
         var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
         Console.WriteLine($"Failed to send analytics data. Response body: {responseBody}");
     }
 }

I get a console response of:
Waiting for connection....
Sending analytics data at 4/17/2024 6:29:36 PM
Event name: mainWindowOpened
Payload: {"client_id":"CLEINTIDNUMBERREDACTED","events":[{"name":"mainWindowOpened"}]}
Status code: NoContent
Analytics data sent successfully.

But no data in Google Analytics Real-time or DebugView. All filters in Google Analytics are disabled. I have a custom event titled mainWindowOpened in Google Analytics but still no data. Any ideas?

So after some experimenting I was able to find this SDK that seems to work fine in sending an event to Google Analytics 4 GA4. GoogleAnalytics.Ga4.Dotnet.Sdk - however it requires a fair amount of dependencies to work.
A simplified solution that only requires System.Text; Newtonsoft.Json; and System.Threading.Tasks; that worked for me is:
        private async Task SendAnalyticsDataAsync(string eventName)
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var measurementId = "XXXXXXXXXX"; // Replace with your Measurement ID
            var apiSecret = "XXXXXXXXXX"; // Replace with your API Secret
            var jsonPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
            {
                client_id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), // Unique client ID for each user/session
                events = new List<object>
{
    new
    {
        name = eventName // Event name indicating a window open action
    }
}
            });
            var content = new StringContent(jsonPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            // Construct the full URL with measurement_id and api_secret as query parameters
            var url = $"https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?measurement_id={measurementId}&api_secret={apiSecret}";

            // Log additional information about the request
            Console.WriteLine($"Sending analytics data at {DateTime.UtcNow}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Event name: {eventName}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Payload: {jsonPayload}");

            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);

            // Log the status code regardless of success or failure
            Console.WriteLine($"Status code: {response.StatusCode}");

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                // Handle success
                Console.WriteLine("Analytics data sent successfully.");
            }
            else
            {
                // Handle error
                // Optionally, log the response body for more details
                var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine($"Failed to send analytics data. Response body: {responseBody}");
            }
        }

And then send the event with:
await SendAnalyticsDataAsync("EVENT_NAME"); //Event name must not include spaces

I am then able to see the event in GA4 / Reports / Library / Events. Should also see the event on the Realtime Overview page in GA4 in the Event Count by Event Name box. However, I don't believe there is a way to trigger realtime users per minute (that only seems to work with Android, iOS, web tracking).
Some additional notes: On the GA4 side, I have it set to web data steam (as opposed to the iOS or Android options). In the data steam settings is where I set an API secret.
Also, worth noting that if the computer running the app is connected to a VPN it might fail causing an exception crash. Here is a solution that include error handling preventing the application from crashing when there are connectivity issues:
private async Task SendAnalyticsDataAsync(string eventName)
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var measurementId = "XXXXXXXXXX"; // Replace with your Measurement ID
    var apiSecret = "XXXXXXXXXX"; // Replace with your API Secret
    var jsonPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
    {
        client_id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), // Unique client ID for each user/session
        events = new List<object>
{
    new
    {
        name = eventName // Event name indicating a window open action
    }
}
    });
    var content = new StringContent(jsonPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var url = $"https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?measurement_id={measurementId}&api_secret={apiSecret}";

    // Attempt to send analytics data with retries
    int maxAttempts = 3;
    for (int attempt = 0; attempt < maxAttempts; attempt++)
    {
        try
        {
            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);
            Console.WriteLine($"Attempt {attempt + 1}: HTTP Status Code: {response.StatusCode}");

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Analytics data sent successfully.");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine($"Failed to send analytics data. Response body: {responseBody}");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Attempt {attempt + 1}: Exception occurred while sending analytics data: {ex.Message}");
            if (attempt < maxAttempts - 1)
            {
                // Wait before retrying
                await Task.Delay(1000 * (int)Math.Pow(2, attempt)); // Exponential back-off
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to send analytics data after multiple attempts.");
            }
        }
    }
}

