GA4 Measurement via standard HTTP Request
I am using GA4 Event Builder to understand how I can do a vanilla HTTP POST request to record a GA4 event. I used the builder to input what I believe to be the correct "Measurement ID" and "API Secret". All the other details such as Client ID and User ID are just arbitrary inputs. When I press the "Validate Event" button on the Event Builder, it pauses for a moment and keeps returning the "This event has not been validated" message.
Even if I try a similar request via HTTP POST (to the https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/mp/collect?measurement_id={measurementId}&api_secret={apiSecret} endpoint), I get a 204 return code (or 200 if in debug mode) but nothing else to tell me that something might be going wrong. I have never seen any event appear in the real-time analytics.
Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong?

why don't you just use gtm or gtag to make an event, check that you've done it correctly and that the event gets to the destination and then check the network request of the successful event. then compare it to yours. A lot easier than using the API secret that nobody needs there and no one ever asked for. MP is weird with their completely unnecessary authentication.

@BNazaruk I am making the request from a .NET application. I'm not sure if it's possible it any other way than via a HTTP POST method?

look at the request in your typical browser, even on this page. It doesn't use MP directly, but it uses a shortcut for it.

I'm not sure how to translate what you're saying into a solution. I already have code from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78343162/google-analytics-4-ga4-send-analytics-from-c-sharp-visual-studio-app but neither this nor Event Builder works for me which is the reason for my question. I assume I'm doing something wrong with either my GA4 setup or parameters I'm passing in.

you are doing something wrong. Comparing the payloads between a working solution and your solution would most likely reveal your mistakes.

Any working solution that you have? I just need a raw HTTP POST packet that works and can try to resolve from there. Although this doesn't explain why the Event Builder is just repeatedly saying "This event has not been validated". I would think that Google would form the correct request so there's something else possibly missing.

are you checking the realtime report for the hit as it comes in?  Are you sure the api_secret is correct?

@BNazaruk GTM only works with webpages.  If this is a .net application there may be no webpage.   Hits must be sent directly though the measurement protocol.

Correct. GTM is mostly for web. The protocol is almost the same though (except the api key), so it doesn't matter at all.

Hi @LindaLawton-DaImTo, yes I am checking to see if a hit comes in but so far nothing. To eliminate possible code problems, I started to use the Event Builder instead but then also ran into the issue and that's left me stumped.

The debug connect endpoint is simply for debugging.  If there is an issue it will tell you that there.  It will NOT send a hit to google analytics
https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/mp/collect

Only the collect endpoint sends hits
https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect

The collect end point will always return 200 it returns no other response there is no validation on that endpoint.
things to check

check the real-time reports to see if the hit came in.  Not the standard reports.
Check your api_secret is correct. If its not the it will be ignored.


Sorry, this doesn't solve the issue. I have tried both debug and non-debug and cannot get it to register a hit.

can you edit your question and show me the hit you are trying to send.

Thanks @Linda - I have updated the post to provide the full HTTP POST URL (not sure how to show POST parameter content).

I need to see the full hit you are sending so i can test it.
